# Same method for different types of classes in Java

Tags: java, xml, post, jaxb

I want to apply the same method to different class name:

```
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(request.getInputStream());

        String l;
        StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader);
        while (( l = br.readLine()) != null) {
            sb1.append(l);
        }
        InputStream sb2 = new ByteArrayInputStream(sb1.toString().getBytes());
        sb1.toString();
        if(sb1.indexOf("CheckStatusRequest") != -1) {
            CheckStatusRequest checkStatusRequest = (CheckStatusRequest)testXmlToObject(sb2);
            System.out.println(checkStatusRequest.getClass());
        }else if(sb1.indexOf("CheckStatusResponse") != -1) {
            CheckStatusResponse checkStatusResponse = (CheckStatusResponse)testXmlToObject1(sb2);
            System.out.println(checkStatusResponse.getClass());
        }else if(sb1.indexOf("Consequences") != -1) {
            Consequences consequences = (Consequences)testXmlToObject2(sb2);
            System.out.println(consequences.getClass());
        }else if(sb1.indexOf("SubscriptionRequest") != -1) {
            SubscriptionRequest subscriptionRequest = (SubscriptionRequest)testXmlToObject3(sb2);
            System.out.println(subscriptionRequest.getClass());
        }else if(sb1.indexOf("TerminateSubscriptionRequest") != -1) {
            TerminateSubscriptionRequest terminateSubscriptionRequest = (TerminateSubscriptionRequest)testXmlToObject4(sb2);
            System.out.println(terminateSubscriptionRequest.getClass());
        }
    }
    public CheckStatusRequest testXmlToObject(InputStream line)  {
        try {
            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(CheckStatusRequest.class);
            Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
            CheckStatusRequest object = (CheckStatusRequest)jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(line);
            return object;
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
    public CheckStatusResponse testXmlToObject1(InputStream line)  {
        try {
            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(CheckStatusResponse.class);
            Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
            CheckStatusResponse object = (CheckStatusResponse)jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(line);
            return object;
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

The solution presented works however I think it is poorly implemented. The method works the same way for each class, what changes is just the type of the object returned. Basically I have the same method for each switch case. I tried to implement a solution where the method was declared as Object and when it was called a cast was made but it didn't work as expected, I get a javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException. 
Can you simplify this code?

Comment: Any creational design pattern will do in your case: `Builder` or `Factory` pattern will suit just fine.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! How exacly should I do it?

Comment: What's wrong with returning ```Object```? If your implementation is correct then returning ```Object``` should be correct too.

Comment: Object doesn't exist I thought it was a general class. Should it be a parent class from the others? I'm not sure it's good practice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do so by using generics. Change your `testXmlToObject` to :

```
public <T> T testXmlToObject(InputStream line, Class<T> classe)  {
    try {
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(classe);
        Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
        T object = (T) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(line);
        return object;
    } catch (JAXBException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

You call the method as `testXmlToObject(line, CheckStatusRequest.class)`